# Can't convert Datetime to Int

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to `SELECT` rows based on two values with this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MYSelect]

    -- Parameters with default values
    @MitarbeiterId          AS int,
    @Wann                   AS datetime2(7)

AS

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT  *
        FROM    [Plan] 
        WHERE   RefMitarbeiterId    =   @MitarbeiterId
        AND     Jahr                <=  YEAR(@Wann)
        AND     Monat               <=  MONTH(@Wann)
        AND     Abgeschlossen       =   0
```

The problem is the following part:

```
        AND     Jahr                <=  YEAR(@Wann)
        AND     Monat               <=  MONTH(@Wann)
```

I don't know why this part is causing a (syntax) problem. With this lines included, using MSSQL Studio, I receive an error `unable to convert DateTime to Integer`. Removing these returns results and has no syntax error. I use `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` elsewhere, so I'm confused why there is a problem here.

This is the `Plan` table:

[image: Plan Table]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing different ways of running this Procedure,
i now think its a bug if you use the View with a Datetime Parameter in **SQL Server Manangement Studio**

because i tested

EXEC

[image]

which works well

then removed my parameters

[image]

this returns an error which tells me that it was unable to convert `'01.07.2014 00:00:00'` to a datetime but it returns the right Rows

if i now do it again with my parameters and add my values

[image]

i get an exception  which tells me the same think like the error above so i have to remove the `'` and then i get the `unable to convert DateTime to Integer` which it's a bug in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

The conditions

```
AND  Jahr <=  YEAR(@Wann)
AND  Monat <= MONTH(@Wann)
```

separate the condition to year and month.

It doesn't mean where the years and month are less then the parameter but where year is less or equal than the year of the parameter **and** the month is less or equal than the month of the parameter.

Using today (2014-06-30) as parameter your query will return every row where with Monat between 1 and 6 for the past and current year: the rows from December 2013, for example, will not be returned.

To get all the rows before the date of the parameter you'll need to change the conditions to

```
AND  ((Jahr = YEAR(@Wann) AND  Monat <= MONTH(@Wann))
   OR  Jahr < YEAR(@Wann))
```

Comment: mhh, i also execute the procedure in different ways with always the same parameters. It looks like a bug if you use a View to rune the procedure it's gives this error but if you run it via `EXEC` it works fine